# MySQL not returning successful results on statement - query looks like it's hanging but is successful

Tags: mysql, java

So we have a script(s) that runs in succession. 
Randomly this task would halt/freeze and error out simply because it did not see a returned response from the MySQL server saying the statement ran fine breaking the entire procedure.
However when manually checking against the DB, the statements all ran fine it's just the script (using JBDC) aborted since it didn't see a response.

Nothing in the error logs, etc.

Is there a setting or reason why MySQL would be doing this?
This is version 5.1 .

I thought of network issues causing this but this seems to happen in 2 different environments, both through a WAN and local LAN .

any ideas?

Comment: What operating system is the script running on? What language is it written in? How long does it execute for? Are there any firewalls between the script host and database host (as this is the most likely culprit)?

Comment: Both on RHEL5.7 and Ubuntu10.04 servers running MySQL5.1 - issue's on both servers.  NO firewalls on the LAN side (private network) , standard firewall (obviously with allows) on the WAN side when replicating this issue outside of the physical environment - these are .SQL statements - these scripts normally take a few seconds to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting up a shell script that runs the SQL scripts or write a program in perl/whatever language which tries to log the errors and return codes from MySQL. Otherwise it is very difficult to troubleshoot without knowing the errors.

You could also add `SHOW ERRORS;` and `SHOW WARNINGS;` to your SQL scripts, but I suspect the problem is not with your queries.